# Does Kitchen's 2' Outlet Spacing Apply if Counter is Beneath Window?

Tags: wiring, receptacle, kitchens, nec

I am remodeling my kitchen and trying to bring it up to code for wiring.

I had an electrician out to scope the project and he mentioned that you need an outlet every 2' of counterspace.

My question is, what about counterspace directly beneath a bay window?

As you can see in the picture, 2' away from the sink in either direction is still beneath the window's edge.

There's ~5" of backsplash to work within.

My question is, does this necessitate an outlet here since technically it's countertop?

Aesthetically I don't like it, as the rest of the outlets will sit higher (48" to top of box) and this would be more like 40" to top of box for the 2 outlets that would have to go in this stretch of backsplash.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The sink area itself is excluded. Measure 2' from each edge of the sink, and you need a receptacle within that space. Note that the rule is not "1 receptacle for every 2' of counter", it is "every point on the counter within 2' of a receptacle". Effectively one every 4' for a long stretch of counter, but sinks and cooktops let you skip some areas.

In your case, I would see if you can put a receptacle turned sideways - i.e., horizontal instead of vertical. 5" is barely enough for vertical but is great for horizontal.

For symmetry, I would put them the same distance from each edge of the sink - e.g., 12" to the left and 12" to the right. They may look odd initially, but you'll get used to them and it will be *very* handy to have receptacles near the sink for certain appliances.

If you keep the peninsula shown in the foreground, keep in mind that receptacle requirements apply there as well. Receptacles can be above the counter (the usual - backsplash or wall), below the counter (but not too far down) or **in** the counter - e.g., pop-up.

Comment: I appreciate the concise answer. 
I do not understand how having an outlet within 1" of the countertop is a good standard as it will 100% get wet? I know the line has to be gfci... but that outlet is 100% getting wet at that high off the counter.

Comment: It isn't behind the sink. Could be up to 2 feet away.